# Printing in Adobe Air Applications

Tags: apache-flex, templates, printing, air, adobe

I have a requirement to print a bill from the AIR application.

Following are the constraints.

1. I need to print to a DotMatrix Printer.
2. I have a complex layout with header, footer and a datagrid with data rolling out to more that one page.
3. I need to have a template to which I will be passing my object.
4. The suffice with the usage of Jasper reports, but I have no server side support.
5. I tried the FlexReport, bentbit and other tools which is optimized for the DotMatrix printers.

Is there a alternative to get the above requirements done. Is there any alternative similar to that of jasper reports without going for a server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys i used the HTML to print from the JavaScript. I made templates in HTML with delimiters matching the print layout, then i passed a Associative Array with necessary details to be printed and passed it on to HTML and printed it from there. Thanks for your replies guys..

Answer (score 1):

You don't need server to do printing,  look at [PrintJob](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/printing/PrintJob.html) class. You can print any sprites on page, and for tables there is [PrintDataGrid](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/printing/PrintDataGrid.html) class with paging support. So, if you can render your complex layout, you can print it. You may want to install some virtual printer for experimenting (I'm using Primo PDF, but there are others.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have done and obtained the result needed. But I needed a support to the DotMatrix Printers. You can find the sample in at http://itechgenie.com/myblog/2011/05/printing-complex-layouts-in-adobe-flex-flexprintjob/.

Comment: Hmm, AIR docs don't anything about printer types. Print job is handled by printer drivers after it is created. What problems do you have with dot-matrix printer?

Comment: As alxx said, Air doesn't control the printer, your OS does.  Air just sends the print job to the OS who handles the rest.

Comment: If the printed output is with images of the headers of datagrid the dot matrix output wont be good. Even if the printAsBitmap is true of false the output seems same. that is the main issue. Instead of taking the UI Objets, if i can pass them to the some API's like jasper, i prefer the output will be much streamlined. sorry if im wrong

Comment: So complex UI looks bad on dot-matrix output? Maybe you should print some simplified version, with only essential details. PrintDataGrid makes (by default) plain table with text, no decorations.

Comment: Thanks all for your replies. have any tried the HTML AIR - JavaScript versions printing. Kindly keep me informed if some one has tried it.